# Why I don't have "configure texmaker" within "option"?

Tags: texmaker, mac

Why I don't have "configure texmaker" within "option" ???

[image]

Comment: May be this is an issue with Mac only, I use Windows. You can contact the developers, or (my advice) install Texmaker 4.5, it is way better with much elegant design.

Comment: Does `texmaker->preferences` exist?

Comment: oh yes, thanks god I get it finally, thank you so much. It looks the same as "configure". btw, apart from this, anything else different from Windows ?

Comment: @MichaelLiu As I neither use windows nor texmaker, I don't know if there are any other differences.

Answer (score 2):

To be respect the common menu standards of mac OSX, the configuration of TeXmaker is called "Preferences" and can be found in the `texmaker` menu entry.

See http://www.tekedam.it/assets/js/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/uploads/164bdff0.png for a screenshot.